# Missing ';' before '*'

Tags: c++

I have looked through a lot of the "Missing ';' before 'x'" questions, but have not found an answer to this particular problem.

```
// ---- Define File ----

#ifndef AnimDefinition_h
#define AnimDefinition_h

// ---- Include ----

#include "AString.h"
#include "FileReader.h"

// ---- Global Constant Variables ----

static const int    MaxAnimations   = 16;
static const int    Blank           = 10;
static const int    EndOfLine       = 59;
static const int    Space           = 32;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
//                      Sprite Animation Definition                     
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
class AnimDefinition
{
private:

    struct Animation
    {
        AString     mAnimationID;
        AString     mLoopTo;
        int         mFrameBegin;
        int         mFrameEnd;
    };

public:

                    AnimDefinition          (void);
                    AnimDefinition          (const char *pFileName);
                    ~AnimDefinition         (void);

    void            ReadFile                ();

    Animation*      Animation               (int pIndex);
    Animation*      Animation               (const char *pFileName);   // The first incident of this error occurs here

private:

    const char      *Scan                   (char *pSource, int &pCounter);

private:

    AString         mDefinitionID;
    FileReader      mFileReader;
    Animation       *mAnimations[MaxAnimations];

    int             mNumberAnimations;
};

// ---- End Definition ----

#endif  //  AnimDefinition_h
```

As mentioned above, the first line with which I hit an error is the definition of the function

```
Animation*      Animation               (const char *pFileName);
```

I have confirmed that AnimDefinition is not being included in either "AString.h" or "FileReader.h". Nor are either of these classes missing a semi-colon anywhere.

Any help would be fantastic.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't give a method the same name as a class, or it will clash with the constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Animation` is a `struct` name and can not be used as function name. Just rename:

```
  Animation* someOtherNameForGettingAnimation(int pIndex);
```

Comment: This was correct, and I actually ended up answering my own question. I'm sorry for wasting your time. Just a silly over-sight on my end.

Answer (score -3):

This is simply a case of me being extremely foolish.

The problem arises where I define a function with the same interface name as the actual type I have predefined.

This line:

```
Animation*      Animation           (int pIndex);
```

I have clearly, incorrectly, called this function "Animation", and to solve the issue I have since named it:

```
Animation*      GetAnimation            (int pIndex);
```

Sorry for wasting anybody's time.

Comment: There's an answer already stating that. You should accept it (mark the tick sign to the left of the answer), instead of posting your own that says the exact same thing.

Comment: I posted the answer whilst the other guy posted his answer.
No need to be aggressive my friend.